# How to change control items style (like picker, switcher, textField)

Tags: xcode

Hi i have a audio player project, but I'd like to change control items style... How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to change control items style... How can I do it?

That depends on the framework and the control. With some controls, notably NSButton and UIButton, you can provide your own images for the control in different states. Other controls, like NSTextField, aren't so readily customizable and will require more work. In some cases, it may not be possible to customize the appearance the way you want, at which point you start thinking about creating your own control instead.

It would help if you'd provide the framework and specific classes that you're looking at modifying.